# How to specify maximum allowable client clock skew for SSL/TLS

Tags: tls

I am investigating the possibility of testing a system which relies on SSL/TLS with a client which, for testing purposes only, has a very different clock time, at least several weeks different from the actual time.

I am aware that if the client's clock is very different from the server, the server might reject the client. Is there any configurable parameter in SSL/TLS which allows the server's acceptable client clock skew to be specified? If so, what is the maximum value of the acceptable clock skew?

A little context. I am working on a software application which is supposed to run for a period of weeks or months. For testing purposes, it would be convenient to start testing at a certain time, and then fast forward through the following weeks and months by changing the client's system clock.

Comment: I believe the client doesn't send its clock time to the server, only the other way around. And even that is gone as of TLS 1.3. Clock skew is only a problem if it messes with certificate expiry.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I am guessing that changing the time range on the certificate is out of reach of the server admin, since the certificate is issued by someone else and presumably any modification isn't allowed. So that suggests that the maximum client clock skew is derived from the certificate, which cannot be changed. Does that seem correct?

Comment: Right. The clock skew for the client isn't given to the server. It's only a problem if the client thinks it's so far in the future or past that a certificate's expiration date is out of range.

Comment: @forest+ through TLS 1.2 (and in SSL) the first 4 bytes of the 'random' (nonce) in both ClientHello and ServerHello is _supposed_ to be  a Unix-style timestamp (seconds since 1970-01-01), but I don't know anyone that checks it. This spec is gone in 1.3, and although not listed in the rev history I believe it was removed because it was agreed to be useless. That said, it seems to me a better simulation of running for a long time would be to DeLorean the clocks at _both_ ends -- you can just use a VM and discard it afterwards.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Even from the client? I was under the impression that it was randomized.

Comment: @forest rfc5246 7.4.1.2 essentially unchanged from 4346 and 2246, and 6101 5.6.1.2.

Comment: Fast-forwarding the system clock may not work as you expect.  For one thing, if this is a standard OS installation it's probably using NTP and is going to be unhappy with you.  Actually speeding up the clock may cause weird secondary effects throughout the OS (timers, etc), which may or may not invalidate your results.  Depending on how you're seeking to deploy this, you may not be able to change SSL-related server time (ie, if you're using a cloud vendor that is handling the SSL termination for you).

Comment: This is also a strange thing to try and test; uptime is nice, but recovery and failover are more useful.  Over weeks or months your network is likely to suffer some sort of interruption, which isn't likely to happen natively in a regular test (so you need an explicit one).  What _exactly_ are you looking to test here?  Just that the application(s) can run for a lengthy amount of time?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse thanks for your interest. We have a collection of timestamped data which should cause specific results to be computed at specific times. We want to verify that the results are computed as expected when the data are replayed. The purpose of fast forwarding the clock is just to go to the times when we expect certain results without having to wait for them to occur in real time.

Comment: The proper way to test time-dependent calculations is to divorce the calculating code from the actual system clock, making the "current time" something that's injected as a dependency, usually as some sort of Func: `() -> CurrentTimeObject`.  See [Java's `Clock` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) and implementations for an example.  For one thing, this makes your tests much simpler (as you are discovering) - you can literally replay a set of data.  It also allows for much stranger time points, like around DST.

Comment: Yes, we have separated the calculations from the nominal time to which they apply, although, I must confess, not in precisely the manner you mentioned. We have unit tests for those calculations. At some point, we believe, the rubber must hit the road and our program and other parts of the system over which we do not have control must play nice together; this led us to consider the system clock.